# Existe alguma maneira em C puro de se implementar conjunto?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, set

Eu estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade e eu preciso checar palavra por palavra de um "dicionário" em arquivo `txt` e comparar essas palavras com as palavras de uma matriz que foi fornecida.

Para facilitar a minha vida (pois vou ter que arranjar alguma forma de deixar meu programa mais rápido), há, em C, a possibilidade de usar variáveis do tipo conjunto? Por exemplo, o "sets" do Python. Ou vou ter que fazer tudo "na mão" mesmo?

Comment: c++ oferece operações matemáticas de conjunto para seus containers de forma genérica. Veja um exemplo para calcular diferença usando `std::set_difference`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference. Se resolver mudar as tags da pergunta para c++ me avisa via comment que respondo com exemplos de uso explicando.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Não diretamente, você vai ter que implementar o estrutura de dados.

Uma biblioteca que já implementa isto é a [GNULib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/), mas até fazer funcionar você já se virou de outra forma. Só vale a pena para uso mais intensivo, não para quebrar um galho.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que em C você não consiga utilizar funções como as que o Set do Python permite, as comparações deveriam ser feitas "manualmente", você poderia utilizar um vetor para armazenar todas as palavras e comparar através de um laço de repetição.

Se estiver comparando somente uma informação com outra informação pode-se utilizar um vetor simples, mas caso necessite comparar mais de uma informação ao mesmo tempo, você pode fazer uma struct e fazer uma array de structs.

Answer (score -3):

Pode fazer em C++, troque a extensão de `.c` para `.cpp` e use o compilador **g++** em vez do **gcc**.
Você pode usar o `vector`, `set`, `queue`, `map`, ...
tem vários, da uma olhada em: http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Exemplo:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    numbers.push_back(42);
    numbers.push_back(314159); 

    for (int i : numbers) { // c++11 range-based for loop
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu "acho" que a pergunta é de C e não C++...

Comment: E este exemplo não usa `set`.

Comment: Eu achei a resposta valida, muitas vezes as pessoas usam o C por desconhecer as facilidades do C++, se ele quer algo ao estilo python deve usar algo mais moderno tipo c++, ele não usa set no exemplo mas como ele mesmo disse na descrição pode ser adptado para: vector, set, queue, map